# Automate a shell script using variables from a txt file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a list of servers in a addresses.txt file in the following format

```
xx.xxx.xx.xx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx
xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

The ip addresses change everyday and I get a new .txt file. The number of servers might change everyday. Im using a Mac so Im using csshx.

I'm trying to csshx into the servers so I need to create a command like this everyday.

`csshx -login username --ssh_args "-i  ~/.ssh/sshkey" xx.xxx.xx.xx xx.xxx.xxx.xx xxx.xx.xx.xx.`

Is there a way to create a shell script so that I can just run the `cssh -login username --ssh_args "-i  ~/.ssh/sshkey"` part and automate the rest of the line using variables from the addresses.txt file? I was thinking of using a for loop but the command needs to be in 1 line.

Comment: haha okay I did not think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional way would be with backtick or `$()` command substitution and `cat` to output the file:

```
csshx -login username --ssh_args "-i ~/.ssh/sshkey" `cat addresses.txt`
```

More modern shells allow you to replace `cat` with `<`:

```
csshx -login username --ssh_args "-i ~/.ssh/sshkey" $(< addresses.txt)
```

Any whitespace in the file is treated as an argument separator, so the server addresses may be separated either by newlines or by spaces/tabs.

Comment: [Why is `$(...)` preferred over backticks?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: re. `$( )` being preferred over backticks, in writing scripts I definitely prefer and recommend `$( )`, but for interactive use where the command substitution is typically simple, I must admit I favour the backticks for being quicker to type.

Comment: Fails if there are spaces tabs in the file, in this case there are none

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes, any whitespace is treated as a separator, but since the question was about hostnames/addresses, one might even consider this a feature.

Comment: @Shawn : You can not nest backticks.